# SurfaceView refuses to create a 32-bit surface for me

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm moving my app away from `NativeActivity` because I want to do more things on the Java side and less things in C. However, I still want to keep the renderer in C. That's why I'm using an `Activity` which has a `SurfaceView` as its main view.

When I used `NativeActivity`, `ANativeWindow_getFormat()` returned `RGBX_8888` which was just fine. With my new renderer based on `SurfaceView`, however, my `surfaceChanged()` callback always receives `RGB_565` as the pixel format which looks really ugly because it only has 65536 colors and gradients look pretty cheap in 16 bits.

So I tried to add the following code to my Activity's `onCreate()` before calling `setContentView()`:

```
getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBX_8888);
```

This indeed solves the problem on my Nexus 5X device running Android 8 but on my Nexus 9 tablet running Android 7 it doesn't work and I still get 16-bit surfaces.

What is confusing me, however, is the fact that when using `NativeActivity` on my Nexus 9 tablet running Android 7 I actually *get* `RGBX_8888` surfaces! So this definitely is *not* a hardware/system limitation on Nexus 9/Android 7. It works for `NativeActivity`, but not for my `SurfaceView`.

What is even more confusing is that when peeking into the Android source codes, you can see that `NativeActivity` actually explicitly request `RGB_565` in its `onCreate` ([see here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/app/NativeActivity.java)) but still I get `RGBX_8888` when I call `ANativeWindow_getFormat()` on my Nexus 9/Android 7. This is of course fine with me but of course it makes me wonder where the `RGBX_8888` surface actually comes from because `NativeActivity` requests a `RGB_565` surface.

To cut a long story short: Basically, all I need to know is how I can force my `SurfaceView` to use a `RGBX_8888` surface on my Nexus 9/Android 7. On my Nexus 5X/Android 8 the code shown above does the trick but it doesn't work on the Nexus 9. But since `NativeActivity` can do it on the Nexus 9, it must be possible on this device as well. I just don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, I was able to solve this by setting `EGL_RED_SIZE`, `EGL_GREEN_SIZE` and `EGL_BLUE_SIZE` to 8 when calling `eglChooseConfig()` on the native side.